# Getting a Syntax error with an expression containing 10#

Tags: linux, bash, token, octal

```
#!/bin/bash
startdate=2009-02-21
enddate=2009-11-30
var=$startdate
while true
do
echo $var
touch $var.txt

#it's line 9
[[ "10#$var" -ge "$enddate" ]] || break

var=$(date +%Y-%m-%d --date "$var +1 day")
done
```

It returns the error

```
line 9:value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

Evidently, the error is in the expression `10#`, but I can't think of a different way how to write the string, besides the ones I've already tried.

Comment: "10#$var" does't make sence, `[[ "$var" -ge "$enddate" ]] || break` should work

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `... && break` -- with an OR there, it'll exit on the first pass (unless `startdate` >= `enddate`, in which case it'll run forever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your dates into seconds then do the comparison, this will be a better approach -

```
startdate=$(date -d 2009-02-21 +%s)
enddate=$(date -d 2009-11-30 +%s)
...
[[ "$startdate" -ge "$enddate" ]] || break
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the whole date as a numeric expression, so 2009-02-01 is interpreted as 2009 - 2 - 1, i.e. 2009 - 3 = 2006. Try the following to see:

```
echo $(( 10#$var ))
```

But numbers starting with a 0 are interpreted as octal numbers, but 08 in so 2009-03-08 can't be interpreted as octal, as only digits 0-7 are permitted in octal numbers.

Maybe you need to compare the dates as string, not as numeric expressions?

```
[[ $var == $enddate || $var > $enddate ]] && break
```

Note I also changed `||` to `&&`. Also, `>=` doesn't exist, but you can replace the double comparison with

```
[[ ! $var < $enddate ]]
```

Comment: You could also use `[[ ! $var < $enddate ]] && break`